# Barchart design in react native chat kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bar-chart, react-native-chart-kit

I am using BarChart from react native chat kit

and i want to achieve following design
[image]

so far i have reached this but still not able to achieve fully..
[image]

kindly help me in the actual bar design

this is my code

```
              <BarChart
                data={chartData}
                width={400}
                height={160}
                chartConfig={chartConfig}
                showValuesOnTopOfBars={true}
                showBarTops={false}
                withHorizontalLabels={false}
               />
```

//config

```
const chartConfig = {
backgroundGradientFrom: '#ffffff',
fillShadowGradient: '#4084F4',
decimalPlaces: 0,
barPercentage: 0.5,
fillShadowGradientOpacity: 1,
backgroundGradientFromOpacity: 1,
backgroundGradientTo: '#ffffff',
spacingInner: 0.7,
backgroundGradientToOpacity: 1,
color: () => `#4084F4`,
labelColor: () => `black`,
withShadow: false,

propsForBackgroundLines: {
  strokeWidth: 0,
},
```

};

Comment: post your code to give a reference

Comment: @Krismu please check now i have added the code

Comment: The styling of Charts in this library seems very limited. You can set rounded corners with barRadius but I think having those grey background bars is impossible. Try using the stackedBarChart instead if you need those and stack a "background bar" on top with height = maxHeight - barHeight

Comment: <StackedBarChart
                    data={data}
                    width={400}
                    height={160}
                    chartConfig={chartConfig}
                    showValuesOnTopOfBars={true}
                    showBarTops={false}
                    withHorizontalLabels={false}
                  />
how to adjust height here? and radius

Answer (score 0):

```
const chartConfig = {
  backgroundGradientFrom: 'white',
  backgroundGradientFromOpacity: 'white',
  backgroundGradientTo: 'white',
  color: () => 'red',
  // fillShadowGradient: 'green',
  fillShadowGradientOpacity: 1,
  labelColor: () => `rgba(85, 139, 229)`,
  barPercentage: 0.3,
  barRadius: 5,
  propsForBackgroundLines: {
    strokeWidth: 1,
    strokeDasharray: null,
    stroke: '#F0F0F0',
  },
 
};


 <BarChart
                data={AllTimeGraphDATA}
                // width={width}
                // height={height}
                width={width - 20}
                height={height * 0.24}
                chartConfig={chartConfig}
                showBarTops={false}
                yAxisLabel={''}
                fromZero={true}
                segments={2}

               
              />


Apply this code It will definitely work
```